# Download Binary File using WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest with SSO Authentication, No Password, Multiple Redirects

Tags: vba, single-sign-on, windows-authentication, winhttp, winhttprequest

Using VB and WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5.1, I need to automate the download of a binary file for users that resides on a network share, requiring SSO authentication, without hardcoding or requiring a user to enter their password.

I have been reviewing solutions on the web for awhile now and the following VB is the closest I've gotten. I am having problems with the multiple redirects, which I am downloading instead of the file.

```
Public Sub download_SCData_test()
On Error GoTo err_me
Dim fData '() As Byte
Dim count As Long
Dim fileNum As Long
Dim ado_strm As Object
Dim winHTTP As New winHTTP.WinHttpRequest
Dim destPath As String
Dim destPath2 As String
Dim fileURL As String
Dim mainURL1 As String
Dim mainURL2 As String

' HttpRequest SetCredentials flags
' It might also be necessary to supply credentials to the proxy if you connect to the Internet through a proxy that requires authentication.
Const CREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER = 0
Const CREDENTIALS_FOR_PROXY = 1
Const HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_PROXY = 2


mainURL1 = "http://wsso.someplace.on.the.web:XXXX/redirect.html?URL=https://someplace.on.the.web/quality/data_metrics/mac/"
mainURL2 = "http://wsso.someplace.on.the.web:XXXX/redirect.html?URL=https://someplace.on.the.web/quality/data_metrics/mac/"

'fileURL = "http://wsso.someplace.on.the.web:XXXX/redirect.html?URL=https://someplace.on.the.web/quality/data_metrics/mac/data.xlsb"
fileURL = "\\serverXXX\webdata\quality\data_metrics\mac\data.xlsb"

destPath = "C:\Temp\data.xlsb"
destPath2 = "C:\Temp\data2.xlsb"

With winHTTP
    .SetProxy proxysetting:=HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_PROXY, ProxyServer:="wsso.someplace.on.the.web:XXXX", BypassList:="*.someplace.on.the.web"

    .Option(Option:=WinHttpRequestOption_SslErrorIgnoreFlags) = 13056
    .Option(Option:=WinHttpRequestOption_MaxAutomaticRedirects) = 20 'default 10
    .Option(Option:=WinHttpRequestOption_EnableHttpsToHttpRedirects) = True
    .Option(Option:=WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects) = True
    .Option(Option:=WinHttpRequestOption_RevertImpersonationOverSsl) = True

    .SetTimeouts 30000, 30000, 30000, 30000 'ms - resolve, connect, send, receive

    ' Send a request to the server and wait for a response.
    'POST authentication string to the main website address not to the direct file address
    .Open Method:="POST", URL:=mainURL1, async:=False

    '.SetCredentials UserName:="server\user", Password:="pass", Flags:=CREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER ' this line has no effect

    'strAuthenticate = "start-url=%2F&user=" & myuser & "&password=" & mypass & "&switch=Log+In"

    .setRequestHeader Header:="Content-Type", Value:="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .setRequestHeader Header:="Date", Value:=Date

    .send   'body:=strAuthenticate
    If Not .WaitForResponse(TimeOut:=30000) Then MsgBox "timeout!": GoTo exit_me

    Sleep 2000

    .Open Method:="POST", URL:=mainURL2, async:=False
    .send   'body:=strAuthenticate
    If Not .WaitForResponse(TimeOut:=30000) Then MsgBox "timeout!": GoTo exit_me

    Sleep 2000

    .Open Method:="GET", URL:=fileURL, async:=True
    .send

    If Not .WaitForResponse(TimeOut:=30000) Then MsgBox "timeout!": GoTo exit_me

    Sleep 2000

    Do While InStr(1, .responseText, "function WSSORedirect()", vbTextCompare)
        Sleep 2000
        count = count + 1: If count > 2 Then Exit Do

        Debug.Print InStr(1, .responseText, "function WSSORedirect()", vbTextCompare)

        If InStr(1, .responseText, "function WSSORedirect()", vbTextCompare) < 1 Then MsgBox "any luck?"

        .Open Method:="GET", URL:=fileURL, async:=True
        .send
        If Not .WaitForResponse(TimeOut:=30000) Then MsgBox "timeout!": GoTo exit_me


        Debug.Print count
        Sleep 2000
    Loop

    Sleep 2000

    fData = .responseBody

    ' Display the results of the request.
    Debug.Print "Credentials: "
    Debug.Print .Status & "   " & .StatusText
    Debug.Print .getAllResponseHeaders
End With


If Dir(destPath) <> vbNullString Then Kill destPath

fileNum = FreeFile
Open destPath For Binary Access Write As #fileNum
Put #fileNum, 1, fData
Close #fileNum


If Dir(destPath2) <> vbNullString Then Kill destPath2

Set strm = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
With strm
    .Type = 1
    .Open
    .Write winHTTP.responseBody
    .SaveToFile destPath2, 2 'overwrite
End With

MsgBox "Completed. Check 'C:\Temp\'.", vbInformation, "execution completed"
exit_me:
On Error Resume Next
Set winHTTP = Nothing
Exit Sub
eerr_me:
Err.clear
Resume Next
End Sub
```

**Response Headers**

```
Credentials: 
200   OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Date: Sun, 21 Feb 2016 22:52:06 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=495
Content-Length: 1975
Content-Type: text/html
Last-Modified: Fri, 17 Aug 2012 17:01:12 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "XXXXXX-XXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
Server: Apache/X.X.XX (Unix) mod_ssl/X.X.XX OpenSSL/X.X.XX XXX/X
```

**Resultant download** is still a WSSO redirect page not the file.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
WSSORedirect();

function WSSORedirect() {
    var destinationURL = window.location.search;
    if (destinationURL.substring(0, 5).toUpperCase() != "?URL=") {
        destinationURL = "";
    }
    else {
        destinationURL = destinationURL.substring(5, destinationURL.length);
    }

    if (destinationURL == "") {
        document.writeln("redirect.html error - no URL.  Usage: redirect.html?URL=[destination URL]");
        document.close();
        return;
    }

    location.replace(destinationURL);
}
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you use the file download response header as a trigger instead of checking the function?

Comment: Jules--thanks for the suggestion.

I discovered that I am actually downloading the 2nd/final redirect page just before the file download prompt, if navigating via the browser.  So, authentication seems to work.  This page is supposed to run 'WSSORedirect();'.  How do I download the file instead of the HTML redirect page?  Do I need to trigger the download somehow?  It's not a large file, so even with a delay, it's not coming through.

Comment: In your wait loop, getAllResponseHeader in to a variable and check for "filename" string in the variable.

Comment: `Do While InStr(1, .getAllResponseHeaders, "data.xlsb", vbTextCompare) < 1`

Gave it a try, even with long waits with DoEvents, still no filename found. 
Other ideas?

Comment: Take a look at this article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/837104

Comment: I have attempted the same solution with the XMLHttp object, with similar results.
`Dim o_xmlHTTP As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    With o_xmlHTTP
        .Open bstrMethod:="POST", bstrUrl:=wssoURL, varasync:=False
        .setRequestHeader bstrHeader:="Content-Type", bstrValue:="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send 'varbody:="authtype=&gcBase=&loption=Windows+2000
        Do While .ReadyState <> 4 And .Status <> 200: DoEvents: Loop
        .Open bstrMethod:="GET", bstrUrl:=fileURL, varasync:=False
        .setRequestHeader bstrHeader:="Connection", bstrValue:="keep-alive"
        .send`

Comment: In your case, redirect is performed on the client side not on the server side. XMLHttp and winhttprequest can't perform javascript action. Alternatively, you may want to use internetexplorer.application. Sorry can't help you much as I have no idea how your system works.